# Suppress Non-Matching Lines in Grep

Tags: linux, bash, grep

Running `service --status-all | grep "firestarter"` in Ubuntu shows the entire output of `service --status-all` with the text "firestarter" highlighted in red. How do you get grep to only show the line that contains the matched text, and hide everything else?

Comment: Question for [Unix/Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) -

Comment: LOL !! @Cerin - http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe `service --status-all` writes to stderr, not stdout? Then you can use

```
service --status-all 2>&1 | grep firestarter
```

Comment: Good answer. I will add --color to display it in red: `service --status-all 2>&1 | grep sudo --color`

Comment: `service` only writes the errors to stderr, like `[ 20:51 root@host ~ ]$ service --status-all | grep httpd
Failed to open PID file: Permission denied`, all the regular output goes to stdout.

Comment: @chown what OS? I have Ubuntu and it works perfectly

Comment: I've got a centos, ubuntu, and fedora box.  Actually, it would depend on the script in `/etc/init.d/[SERVICE_SCRIPT]`, but normally they follow the general standards of regular text to stdout and errors to stderr.

Comment: Oh yes you are right, good call

Comment: Executing this command: `service --status-all | grep --color '.'` suggest that the program output to both stdout and stderr. For example lines with `[?]` are outputed to stderr and lines with `[-]` or `[+]` are outputed to stdout. This means the program does not know in what state the service are so it print the unknown status to stderr.

Answer (score 3):

You must have some weird env variables set.  Try this:

```
service --status-all | `which grep` firestarter
```

Or:

```
service --status-all | /bin/grep firestarter
```

And show the output of `env` and `alias` if possible so we can see whats wrong with your `grep` command.

---

For me, I have:

```
[ 13:55 jon@host ~ ]$ echo $GREP_OPTIONS
--color=always
```

You probably have something set there, and/or in `GREP_COLOR` that is causing this.

Answer (score 2):

if you don't want to use an alias, but the original command, you could try "\cmd". e.g.

```
service --status-all | \grep "firestarter"
```